# Display emails before sending with Javascript

Tags: javascript, email

I am trying to create a script that will open the default email client, fill in certain variables but still allow the user to make changes and send. Right now my script will send the email (email.send) but I am looking for a way for the email to be displayed rather than sent. Here is the code:

```
var email = new Email()
email.subject = item.PO_ID

email.to = [item.BUYER_EMAIL, "accounting@test.com", "user@test.com"]

email.body = "Test body"

email.send()
```

What do I change `.send()` to?

Comment: Why not add these variables prior to sending email via some form? What if I don't have *default email client* set?

Comment: `new Email`? What is this? Some library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but have you tried using using `window.location()` and sending the browser to something like:

```
mailto:accounting@test.com?subject=Test&body=Test Body
```

Replacing the email, subject and body using JS.